# In show touches of Android, What does the color lines mean

Tags: android

When I turned on the debug mode.Set "USB debugging",and turn on "Show touches".It should show lines when I touch in the screen.
[image]

Could you tell me what is the meaning of the lines' color.
The blue line is ..?
the red line is ..?
and the purple is ...?

Comment: +1. I am also curious what this colors mean. I thing they are related with OnTouchUp and Velocity X,Y.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some more research I have noticed that:

- **blue line** finishes exactly where the user stops pressing the screen, so blue line indicates touch.
- I would say that **pink line (red line?)** indicates stroke velocity (it is shorter when the stroke is slow and longer when we draw quickly, and is related with values shown in the top of the screen `Vx`, `Vy`)
- **purple line** is some kind of approximation (because it
  doesn't cover neither with blue or pink lines, so it is not directly related with where we draw - there is some indirect relation)

This means, that in the picture above, he stopped touching the screen in the `USB Debugging` row.

Answer (score 1):

It shows where exactly you are touching on the screen(i.e, the visual feedback for touches) and the color represents the amount of pressure you are giving while touching for example the blue line indicating a strong touch,red for medium and purple for mild touch. Also, you can try pointer location for XY intersection point.

Comment: They may actually indicate pressure or confidence or similar.  The only way I can get red instead of blue is if my finger is still moving as I lift it off the screen - then the tail end of the trace goes through hues of red.

Comment: @Marek - review of what appears to be the relevant source code -  `PointerLocationView.java` for example at  https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/5cb0f2184656642160e9ac032d0646f766058a5b/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/PointerLocationView.java seems to indicate that **it is in fact the pressure**, or what passes for pressure in the Android touch event code.

Comment: You can check it out by yourself - try to press it hard, soft, or almost not press - color is same. I think that it is related with last touchUp() and velocity (indicates speed of stroke or something. This is just a guess though, but I am almost sure it is not a pressure - and everyone can check it. Almost doesn't mean 100% sure though. Also,purple line appears many times far away from last pressed point, so it can't be a pressure.